# Should I play while charging

Tags: charging, motorola-electrify

Is it okay to use my tablet while charging it? I just got a new tablet. I havn't done it cause I wasn't sure.

Comment: See: [Will playing a game in a Android phone while charging damage or cause harm to the battery or the phone?](/q/37052/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using a tablet while charging should not drain battery life. Keep in mind that doing that will cause the device to charge slower.

Also, if you do something cpu intensive (like 3d game) it can become a little hot. Don't worry. I had a tablet that became very, very hot (like a container coming out of a microwave), yet it didn't melt.